# Use fstab generated by wic in other FSTYPE used by SWUpdate

Tags: yocto, swupdate, yocto-wic

I am trying to implement an update for a system based on yocto using swupdate. The issue is that I actually don't have the same content in the `.wic` and `.tar.gz` versions of the image. The first one has the partition table generated from the `.wks` file, the other has the default one from `poky`.

#### Tl;dr

The short version of my question is: can I get the `/etc/fstab` generated by `wic` in the `rootfs` for exports other than `.wic`?

### The configuration

So I have a projet which generates three files as an output

```
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "wic.bz2 wic.bmap tar.gz"
```

On top of that I have a `my-project-swu` recipe that uses the base image to generate a `.swu` file

```
IMAGE_DEPENDS = "my-project-full"
SWUPDATE_IMAGES = " \
    my-project-full \
"
SWUPDATE_IMAGES_FSTYPES[my-project-full] = ".tar.gz"
```

And the `wic` files are generated from the following `wks` configuration

```
part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4096
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root --align 4096 --size=1G
part --ondisk mmcblk0 --label alt_rootfs --align 4096  --size=1G
part /data       --size 1G --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label data --align 4096
```

### The issue

When I first deploy my image using `bmaptool` the `/etc/fstab` file contains the following content

```
/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults              1  1
# Some default values here ...

/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults        0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p4  /data   ext4    defaults        0       0
```

This includes the `/boot` partition that contains the `u-boot` environment used by `SWUpdate` as well as a data partition.

But then after a succesful update the file contains :

```
/dev/root            /                    auto       defaults              1  1
# Some default values here ...
```

So now `/boot` is missing, so trying to signal to `u-boot` that booting was successful doesn't work, and the `/data` partition isn't available either. Right now I could copy the file from one root to the next after the update, but that only works while I have a writeable root, which probably won't always be the case.

If I look in the build directory I do see the two files `./tmp-glibc/work/raspberrypi3_64-oe-linux/my-project-full/1.0-r0/build-wic/fstab`  has the complete version, and `./tmp-glibc/work/raspberrypi3_64-oe-linux/my-project-full/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/fstab`  has the default one. To my understanding this is to be expected because `wic` is only executed automatically for the `.wic` output, so that adding or removing the `.wic` output doesn't affect unrelated outputs.

### Possible solutions?

The simplest solution to that issue is to replace the default `fstab` file by an hardcoded one, but this means that the information has to stay consistent between the `wks` and `fstab` ones, I'd rather just use the file generated by `wic` as the basis for the `.swu` file.

One other solution would be to use directly the `.wic` file as an input for my update. While I guess this is possible this doesn't look like a standard thing to do, nor the proper way.

So ideally I'd rather have the `fstab` I get in the `.wic` directly in the `rootfs`, so that no matter which format is used for the export, the partitions are used consistently, but I don't understand how I'd be able to do that.